# how to add results of calculation into a dataframe with dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have the following problem: I get an error when trying to add 'time' and 'y_corrected' into the new dataframe.

I need to calculate a variable, 'y_corrected', and add it to a new dataframe. In order to calculate this variable, I use the group function to loop through the dataset based on two criteria: filename and treatment. The final dataframe should contain filename, treatment, time, y_corrected.

```
file = pd.read_excel(r'C:.....xlsx')
grouped = file.groupby(['File name', 'Treatment'])

########################################  output dataframe #####################################
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['File name','Treatment', 'Time', 'y_corrected'])
new.columns = ['File name', 'Treatment', 'Time', 'y_corrected']

######################################## correction ########################################
for key, g in grouped:
  a = g['y'].max()
  b = g['y'].min()

  y_corrected = (g['y'] - b) / a

  row = {'File name': key[0], 'Treatment': key[1],  'Time': time[2], 'y_corrected': y_corrected[3]}
  new = new.append(row, ignore_index=True)

print(new)
```

This is the error:
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to loop through the different groups. You only have to use pandas magic on your dataframe:

```
file = pd.read_excel(r'C:.....xlsx')

file['y_corrected'] = file.groupby(['File name', 'Treatment'])['y'].apply(lambda x: (x-min(x))/max(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, you could try passing values as lists in your "row" object, I've got into some similar problems before when using dataframe.append(). For example:

`row = {'File name': [key[0]], 'Treatment': [key[1]] ....`

Answer (score 0):

Because g['y'] is a series, y_corrected is also a series equal to the length of a group.

```
y_corrected = (g['y'] - b) / a
```

y_corrected[3] doesn't work.  You should loop over those values again to get the row values (I left out 'time' because that doesn't seem relevant to the problem).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'Z', 1.0],
                     ['A', 'Z', 0.5],
                     ['A', 'Y', 1.5],
                     ['A', 'Y', 0.5],
                     ['B', 'Z', 1.0],
                     ['B', 'Z', 0.5],
                     ['B', 'Y', 1.5],
                     ['B', 'Y', 0.5],
                     ],
                    columns=['File name', 'Treatment', 'y']
                    )
grouped = df.groupby(['File name', 'Treatment'])

########################################  output dataframe #####################################
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['File name', 'Treatment', 'y_corrected'])
new.columns = ['File name', 'Treatment', 'y_corrected']

######################################## correction ########################################
for key, g in grouped:
    a = g['y'].max()
    b = g['y'].min()

    y_corrected = (g['y'] - b) / a

    for idx, y_corrected_ in y_corrected.items():
        row = {'File name': key[0], 'Treatment': key[1], 'y_corrected': y_corrected_}
        new = new.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

A simpler way to solve this problem would be to perform the operation directly on your group.

```
def correction(s):
    return (s - s.min()) / s.max()

df['y_corrected'] = grouped.apply(correction)

print(df)
```

Gives:

```
  File name Treatment    y  y_corrected
0         A         Z  1.0     0.500000
1         A         Z  0.5     0.000000
2         A         Y  1.5     0.666667
3         A         Y  0.5     0.000000
4         B         Z  1.0     0.500000
5         B         Z  0.5     0.000000
6         B         Y  1.5     0.666667
7         B         Y  0.5     0.000000
```